# Update Payment Information of an Express Connect Account on Stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have onboarded an Express Connect account on Stripe.

Now, I wish to allow the users update their information at will so I attempted the following code:

```
 const accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
    account: accId,
    refresh_url: `${origin}/stripe/refresh_url`,
    return_url: `${origin}/stripe/return_url`,
    type: 'account_update', //I used update here
  });
```

So, I set the type to `account_update` but I'm getting a stripe error that I can't use type `account_update` on express accounts that only custom accounts accepts that.

I don't want to deal with custom accounts, I want stripe to be solely responsible for capturing and updating all their details which is what Express seems to solve.

So, how else can I let my Express connect accounts update their info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the Express account is not fully onboarded, you can create an AccountLink with `type: 'account_onboarding'` to finish the onboarding. But if the Express account is already onboarded, then you can directly redirect them to their Express dashboard with a [login link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/account/create_login_link). Once on the Express dashboard they will be able to update some of their information.

In Node.js you can create an login link like this:this:

```
const loginLink = await stripe.accounts.createLoginLink('acct_xxx');
```